# bin data returned by regplot changed slightly for each running

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression

I want to plot regression based on mean values. I use the regplot of seaborn, but found that the regression function changed slightly at each run. Do you know how to sovle it? Thank you.

Here is the test script, you may find the R2 changed each time

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score


# Plot barplot with linear fit
def get_data_XYE(p):
    x_list = []
    lower_list = []
    upper_list = []
    for line in p.lines:
        x_list.append(line.get_xdata()[0])
        lower_list.append(line.get_ydata()[0])
        upper_list.append(line.get_ydata()[1])
    y = 0.5 * (np.asarray(lower_list) + np.asarray(upper_list))
    y_error = np.asarray(upper_list) - y
    x = np.asarray(x_list)
    return x, y, y_error

thres = 140
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

H = pd.DataFrame([48,22,27,35,49,142,141,151,151,305,841,726,566,222,86,187,103,176,81,96,304,170,
                  109,123,281,210,534,680,594,327,371,674,39,7,14,29,136,36,55,61,99,146,6,9,17,91,
                  192,194,195,209,207,220,238,197,227,229,14,90,73,109,7,8,52,84,6,30,20,36,113,22,
                  55,124,59,58,52,73,69,58,49,39,136,251,84,48,88,100,93,112,150,151,163,173,134,
                  468,296,103,81,84,127,392,55,80,54,45,51,72,62,54,54,82,105,49,265,130,95,81,54,
                  123,98,67,39,117,140,83,102,92,106,90,57,59,43,87,79,111,95,87,112,35,26,68,37,74,
                  92,113,104,103,74,74,179,173,285,286,166,157,221,177,147,152,144,181,16,182,185,
                  170,165,143,142,35,35,77,97,54,48,264,29,43,157,154,492,261,276,181,115,85,92,157,
                  334,132,16,75,75,235,375,361,303,48,108,145,137,70,63,56,56,62,86,145,41,94,549,
                  256,39,159,153,13,13,14,14,204,192,88,140,94,83,219,190,113,87,94])
R = pd.DataFrame([37,40,30,29,24,23,27,12,21,20,34,29,28,27,32,23,29,28,22,28,23,24,29,32,23,18,25,
                  22,29,12,12,14,29,31,30,34,31,22,40,25,36,27,27,29,35,33,25,25,27,27,19,35,26,18,
                  24,25,37,52,47,34,39,40,48,41,44,35,36,53,46,38,44,23,26,26,28,27,21,25,21,20,27,
                  35,24,46,34,22,30,30,30,31,26,25,28,21,31,24,27,33,21,31,33,29,33,32,21,25,22,39,
                  31,34,26,23,18,20,18,34,25,20,12,23,25,21,21,25,31,17,27,28,29,25,24,25,21,24,27,
                  23,22,23,22,22,26,22,19,26,35,33,35,29,26,26,30,22,32,33,33,28,32,26,29,36,37,37,
                  28,24,30,25,20,29,24,33,35,30,32,31,33,40,35,37,24,34,29,27,24,36,26,26,26,27,27,
                  20,17,28,26,34,18,20,20,18,19,23,20,22,25,32,44,41,39,41,40,40,44,36,42,31,32,26,
                  29,23,29,29,28,31,22,29,24,28,28,25])
dat = pd.merge(H,R,left_index=True,right_index=True)
dat.columns=['H','R']

breaks = [6.0,39.0,75.0,117.0,159.0,197.0,238.0,305.0,392.0,492.0,594.0,726.0,841.0]
g = sns.regplot(x='H',y='R',data=dat,fit_reg=False,x_bins=breaks)
dat = get_data_XYE(g)
x = dat[0].reshape(-1,1)
y = dat[1].reshape(-1,1)
mask = x<thres
reg.fit(x[mask].reshape(-1, 1),y[mask])
yp = reg.coef_*x[mask]+reg.intercept_
r2 = r2_score(y[mask],yp)
g.axes.plot(x[mask], yp, color='red', linewidth=3)
g.axes.legend(labels=[r'$y={:.2f}x+{:.2f},R^2={:.4f}$'.format(reg.coef_.squeeze(),
              reg.intercept_.squeeze(),r2)],loc='upper right')
y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the midpoint between the extent of the confidence intervals for the dependent variable in your regression. But the confidence intervals are computed using a percentile bootstrap, so a) there will be some randomness (control with `seed=`) and b) they will not be symmetric (so this probably isn't how you want to solve your problem).

Comment: You are right, it was controlled by seed parameter.